# Multiple Distinct Not Working in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand what this query does exactly: Not Working

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ART_LINK,ID,SUB_CATEGORY, CATEGORY, ALBUM FROM SONG_AS
```

Comment: Can you share some records that are in the SONG_AS table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assure you, `DISTINCT` works.

- I'm going to use a little mind reading and guess the `Not Working` mean you want just the albums.
- I'm assuming `ID` is the culprit as every song probably has a unique id since the tables named `SONG_AS`
- Hence,  `DISTINCT` returns a record for each unique `ID`

So, leave out `ID` from your select query you should not get a recorded for every song, but for each album.

Comment: What Ray hasn't stated is that "select distinct" works across the **whole row** when it is deciding what is distinct or not. So if you include any column (such as id) which will be different on every row, then every row is by definition distinct. compare your query to `select distinct album from song_as` then try `select distinct category, album from song_as`  for every added column you will get extra rows.